# Prove there exists a basis such that $[T]^\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb{F}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^2$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=0$.
>
> Prove $T=0$ or there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathbb{F}^2$ such that $$[T]^\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

My try:

If $T=0$, then we're done. Suppose $T\neq 0$, so there exists $0\neq v \in \mathbb{F}^2 \ \text{ s.t. } T_v\neq 0$.

Let's take $u \in \mathbb{F}^2$ which is not linear dependent with $v$.

Since $\text{dim}(\mathbb{F}^2)=2$, we get that the set $\mathcal{B}=\{v,u\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}^2$.

Now, I know I need to use that $T^2=0$ and to present $T_v$ and $T_u$ as a linear combination of $v$ and $u$, but not sure how to continue to get the result.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Notice that you have a canonical choice for the second vector $u$, namely $Tv$; how do we know that $\{v, Tv\}$ is not linearly dependent?

Comment: @Travis  not sure, can I get a hint?

Comment: Suppose they *are* linearly dependent; then, since $v \neq 0$, we'd have $T v = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: @Travis And now apply $T$ on both sides?

Comment: What happens if you do that?

Comment: @Travis I get $\lambda T_v = 0$ which contradicts $T_v \neq 0$, or is it possible $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Go back to how we defined $\lambda$; /is/ it possible that $\lambda = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try $u = Tv$...................

Comment: How can I prove $\{v,T_v\}$ is lineary independent?

Comment: $Tv \ne 0$, but $T(Tv)=0$.